# Email 2 case comment - how to remove the original email

Tags: string, email2case

I'm creating a case comment from an inbound email. The created comment already contains the original email (see below).

test reply 2

On Wed, Jun 19, 2013 at 10:12 AM, Support  wrote:

> Dear itay,
>
> Your case #00004763: Test 4 was added a new comment.
>
> Comment: test comment 2
>
> To view this case on the Self-Service Portal, use the link below

I want to include just the reply as a case comment ('test reply 2') without the original email, so far i've used:

```
comment.CommentBody = header + email.TextBody.substringBefore('Support <support@gmail.com>');
```

but it still contains the date...is there a way to achieve that?